# How to split elemts in a column into more columns in python

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have this df:

[image]

I want to split the elements in each column into more columns. Therefore, my output should look like this:

[image]

I've been trying to use the following code:

```
dff = df.columna.str.split(expand=True)
dff
```

But the output is being generated looks like the first image. I'm not sure about how to approach this problem.

Comment: Where, for example, `detergent` comes from? In your original dataframe you don't have this value.

Comment: The second image it is just an example of how my original dataframe should look like. Each element should be in a different column like image 2 shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, you have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columna': ['a,b,c', 'x,y', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i,j,k,l,m']})
```

Then:

```
df = df['columna'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns=lambda x: 'column{}'.format(x))
print(df)
```

Creates:

```
  column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
0       a       b       c    None    None    None    None
1       x       y    None    None    None    None    None
2       d       e       f    None    None    None    None
3       g       h       i       j       k       l       m
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the the columns' names and the delimiter as `','` :

```
dff[['column0','column1','column2','column3','column4','column5']] = dff['columna'].str.split(',',expand=True)
dff
```